# Mongoose aggregation not returning latest document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation that returns a document, but I need it to return a document that is the latest one in the collection messageTrackingId. The one that has the most recent value in the `creationDate` field I have a sort to accomplish this, but I keep getting returned documents that aren't the latest and I'm not sure why. The purpose is to show the user the time stamp of the last message sent between that user and another user regardless of who sent it. appreciate any help.

```
app.get("/api/messages", (req, res, next) => {
  query = {};
  inbox = false;
  messageId = false;
  console.log(req.query.recipientId);
  if (req.query.recipientId) {
    query = { recipientId: req.query.recipientId };
    inbox = true;

    Messages.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { recipientId: req.query.recipientId },
            { creator: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.recipientId) }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          conversant: {
            $cond: [
              { $ne: ["$recipientId", req.query.recipientId] },
              "$recipientId",
              "$creator"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: { creationDate: 1 }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$conversant",
          message: { $last: "$message" },
          recipientId: { $last: "$recipientId" },
          creator: { $last: "$creator" },
          messageTrackingId: { $last: "$messageTrackingId" },
          recipient: { $last: "$recipient" },
          creationDate: { $last: "$creationDate" }
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          let: { creator: "$creator" },
          pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$creator"] } } },
            { $project: { instagramName: 1 } }
          ],
          as: "creatorName"
        }
      }
    ]).then(documents => {


      if (inbox === true) {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "User's Inbox Retrieved!",
          posts: documents
        });
      }

    });
```

I cleared out the message table and sent 3 messsages back and forth to demonstrate. When I reload the page, I only receive 2 of the docs in the JSON response instead of the latest one. Of the 2 received, none of them seem to be the latest either. I'm not sure why it's not returning one. Please see output on page load below.

**Messages :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5e16463be5fcba1d2c56ebb7",
    "creator" : "5e0a1d41f86e1e4234fc1a77",
    "recipient" : "andy",
    "recipientId" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "message" : "First message",
    "messageTrackingId" : "17c4fc99-d92f-46ef-9bae-1408f415287a",
    "creatorName" : "buyer1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-08T21:14:35.104Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5e16464de5fcba1d2c56ebb9",
    "creator" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "recipient" : "buyer1",
    "recipientId" : "5e0a1d41f86e1e4234fc1a77",
    "message" : "Second Message",
    "messageTrackingId" : "17c4fc99-d92f-46ef-9bae-1408f415287a",
    "creatorName" : "andy",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-08T21:14:53.618Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5e16465ce5fcba1d2c56ebbb",
    "creator" : "5e0a1d41f86e1e4234fc1a77",
    "recipient" : "andy",
    "recipientId" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "message" : "Third Message",
    "messageTrackingId" : "17c4fc99-d92f-46ef-9bae-1408f415287a",
    "creatorName" : "buyer1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-08T21:15:08.500Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0
}
```

**users :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5df00d08c713f722909c99c1",
    "email" : "joe@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2b$10$5eWhwL4RNT8TyQRCC191J.myYBwFcJ8hCARqGfofYWUmRaq6jJFQm",
    "instagramName" : "joe",
    "over21" : "Yes",
    "role" : "Artist",
    "fullName" : "testdsfdfsfs",
    "address1" : "adfsdf",
    "address2" : "dssdf",
    "city" : "sdfsdfsdf",
    "state" : "dsffsdsd",
    "zip" : "dsdfsdf",
    "passwordCreated" : ISODate("2020-01-07T23:46:57.861Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "email" : "andy@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2b$10$fNHmIoDb4mX6x.YeMLXHbu2yIaeW6HVQvNpZR8Nt/a4xVFkhxM1Ey",
    "instagramName" : "andy",
    "over21" : "Yes",
    "role" : "Artist",
    "fullName" : "dsfdsfdfdsf",
    "address1" : "111",
    "address2" : "111",
    "city" : "atlanta",
    "state" : "ga",
    "zip" : "33222",
    "passwordCreated" : ISODate("2019-12-19T15:29:46.528Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Required output (Return last message from each user) :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "conversant" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
        "recipient" : "andy"
    },
    "message" : "Third Message",
    "recipientId" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "creator" : "5e0a1d41f86e1e4234fc1a77",
    "messageTrackingId" : "17c4fc99-d92f-46ef-9bae-1408f415287a",
    "recipient" : "andy",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-08T21:15:08.500Z"),
    "creatorName" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
            "instagramName" : "andy"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "conversant" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
        "recipient" : "buyer1"
    },
    "message" : "Second Message",
    "recipientId" : "5e0a1d41f86e1e4234fc1a77",
    "creator" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
    "messageTrackingId" : "17c4fc99-d92f-46ef-9bae-1408f415287a",
    "recipient" : "buyer1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-01-08T21:14:53.618Z"),
    "creatorName" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5df0014e25ee451beccf588a",
            "instagramName" : "andy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I believe it would be better if you provide sample docs & result that you're getting for better understanding on what's happening, It understandable but it would be better with those

Comment: See sample doc above as well. I made some edits too

Comment: If I understand correctly `{
          conversant: {
            $cond: [
              { $ne: ["$recipientId", req.query.recipientId] },
              "$recipientId",
              "$creator"
            ]
          }` at this stage you wanted to group by `recipientId` on a field(since you can't group on two fields for a single value) So you're creating a new field, Is that `$ne` ? I guess it should be `$eq` !!

Comment: I updated the conversant to be ```$eq``` instead of ```nq``` and when I refresh the the page 2 docs that return from JSON response none of the 2 are the latest document.

Comment: I added ```-1```, but issue still persists. Here's an updated version of my code to reference: https://pastebin.com/TWzxhELh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205621/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-user6680).

Comment: If you can create a playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net) you can attract more answerers. At least you can give the sample documents in pure json format as copy-able text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes has to be

1) If I understand correctly at this stage you wanted to group by `recipientId` on a field(since you can't group on two fields for a single value) So you're creating a new field called `conversant`, So it has to be `$eq` or you need to swap `recipientId` & `creator`  & also it has to be `$toString`:

```
{
      $addFields: {
        conversant: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$recipientId", req.query.recipientId] },
            "$recipientId",
            {$toString : "$creator"} 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

2) You don't need this `$sort` stage, as all latest additions to collection will be added at the end (Expecting `creationDate` is once created but never updated) :

```
// Not useful
{
     $sort: { creationDate: 1 }
}
```

Also you need to group by `_id: { conversant: "$conversant", recipient: '$recipient' }` for group on last messages based on `user`. In `$lookup` change to this `let: { conversant: "$_id.conversant" }`.

Try this :

```
 Messages.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { recipientId: req.query.recipientId },
                { creator: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.recipientId) }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            conversant: {
                $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$recipientId", req.query.recipientId] },
                    "$recipientId",
                    { $toString: "$creator" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { conversant: "$conversant", recipient: '$recipient' },
            message: { $last: "$message" },
            recipientId: { $last: "$recipientId" },
            creator: { $last: "$creator" },
            messageTrackingId: { $last: "$messageTrackingId" },
            recipient: { $last: "$recipient" },
            creationDate: { $last: "$creationDate" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: { conversant: "$_id.conversant" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$conversant"] } } },
                { $project: { instagramName: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "creatorName"
        }
    },
     // this is optional only if you wanted to return latest document irrespective of user.
     { $sort: { creationDate: -1 } }
])
```

Comment: From my testing, it appears that when a user sends a message, they have the most up to date document now, which is good, but the recipient seems to be getting a hit or miss on the latest

Comment: I've been logging in and out of each users account back and forth and eventually it will not pull the latest document with that messageTracking Id. This table should have the latest date https://postimg.cc/Lh8wdLH5 , but it should say 3:08:13 https://postimg.cc/p55BW2GG   not 3:07:49